# Preg_replace str if not immediately followed by str

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have been trying for 2 hours, but I can't seem to master regex properly. I would like to replace all html comments from a string, but only if the string is NOT immediately succeeded by a `<br>` tag.

I have the following working nicely already, to remove all html comments from a string:

```
preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/s', '', $str);
```

I am trying to add so that the comment is NOT replaced if it is immediately succeeded by a `<br>` tag. I was thinking something like this (obviously wrong), but can't wrap my head around it:

```
preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->(?!<br>)/s', '', $str);
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: please post an example of what you have and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lazy dot pattern will match as few chars as possible up to the first substring matched with the subsequent pattern, and in your case, that means that once a `<!--` is found, the string that will match `.*?` will be the next one that matches `-->` not followed with `<br>` *even if* it is a closing comment delimiter of the next comment.

What you need to do is to make sure the `.*?` does not match `-->`. Either use a `(?:(?!-->).)*` [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed), or an unrolled version of it:

```
'~<!--[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*-->(?!<br>)~s'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aT8sD3/1)

The `[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*` pattern matches any 0+ chars other than `-` (`[^-]*`) and then 0+ sequences of `-` not followed with `->` (see `-(?!->)`) and then 0+ chars other than `-`.

The `(?:(?!-->).)*` tempered greedy token matches any character (`.`) that does not start a `-->` sequence (`(?!-->)`), zero or more times (`*`).

Comment: I can't say I understand everything, but it seems to work nicely than you very much.

Comment: The point is that `.*?` matches any symbol. That is the problem. A tempered greedy token matches text that is not a starting point of the pattern inside the `(?!...)` negative lookahead. We need to limit that `.*?` and the tempered greedy token is the bes for this scenario. For the unroll the loop principle explanation, see http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop.